# SUMPRODUCT is taking way too long

Tags: excel, sumifs, sumproduct

I have this data:-

[image]

This is what I want to achieve:-

[image]

By selecting the customer as "ABC", the respective amount will show at Jan to Jun.

I can achieve this by using SUMPRODUCT but it takes a long time to process as my data is more than 10K rows. Is there a more efficient way to do this using SUMIFS etc?

Thank You

Comment: I think SUMIFS() is the right way. Please try it and post your effort if it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible to share the formula?

Comment: What's in B1:G1? Dates or Text? Similarly, what's in K3::K14?

Comment: Those are Dates.

Comment: @Bob Which version of excel do you use?

Comment: MsOffice 2019...

Comment: @Bob you've had 2 answers, both of which have had to make assumptions about your setup, both of which would work if those assumptione were correct, neither of which work for you  (according to your comments).  Clearly there is something you aren't telling us.  Time to add more details to your Q: the formula you have now, proper definition of your sample data, what results you actually got from the answers formulas, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that you can paste to L2 in your example and copy down to December.

```
=SUMIF(INDEX(Data,0,1),$L$1,INDEX(Data,0,MATCH(K2,Months,0)))
```

As you see, it has 2 named ranges, `Data` and `Months`.

1. `Data` comprises of all data rows and columns, A1:G9 in your posted example. I think you will want to make this range dynamic, meaning it should adjust in size automatically as you add or delete data. One can do this is the formula but that isn't efficient. Therefore you do it in the name declaration. If you need help with that please don't ask here. It's a different subject: "dynamic named ranges".
2. `Months` should have as many columns as 'Data', not limited to 12. It's important that it should start in the same column as `Data` and that its first field shouldn't hold a date that might become a search criterium of the function.

Column K can also have more than 12 columns. In my setup I used a custom number format `mmm`. Therefore 1/1/21 and 1/1/22 will be displayed identically but the MATCHG function can tell them apart.

I placed a start date into B1 and `=EDATE(B1,1)` into C1, which I copied to the right. Similarly, K2 has `=B1`, K3 `=EDATE(K2,1)` which is copied down. This ensures that column and row captions are aligned.

Comment: It doesn't show the correct output. It show Jan = 0 (correct value is 99), Feb = 99 (correct value is 100), Mar = 100 (correct value is 104),  Apr = 104 (correct value is 107).

Comment: It does. If it shows a wrong one you didn't set it up correctly. My guess is that your `Months` range doesn't start at A1 but you can test with =SUM(Data,0,2)), where 2 is the column of *Data* and =MATCH(K2, Months,0) which should return  the number of the column to sum from. In this way you can find out where to correct your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try on below formula-

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$9,$B$14,INDEX($B$2:$G$9,,MATCH($A15,$B$1:$G$1,0)))
```

[image]

If they are true date then try below array formula. Excel365 no need array entry.

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$9,$B$14,INDEX($B$2:$G$9,,MATCH(MONTH($A15),MONTH($B$1:$G$1),0)))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

> ***Edit:*** If your data is structed as like your provided sample then below formula will more efficient.

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(B:G,,ROW($A1)),A:A,$J$1)
```

[image]

Comment: Great, it works better that SUMPRODUCT. Is it possible to select the entire row instead of preset it eg $A$2:SA$9 to A:A or $B$2:$G$9 to B:G? My data has many rows & it changes daily.

Comment: @Bob If your data is structed in well manner then you can handle it more efficiently. See my edited answer. If you found it working then please mark it as answered (tick mark).

Comment: Tried that but it doesn't work if i change the mth - instead of Jan to June, now Jun to Jan. The numbers remain the same.

Comment: Can you share a sample workbook via google drive.